# React Native in Expo: Asyncstorage gets cleared when app refreshes

Tags: android, react-native, expo

This is going to be a dumb question cause I couldn't show any code as I don't what happened or where this is possible happening.

I have been developing a react native app for months now and from the I only have to log in my account once then persist the token using `Asynstorage` then I can develop the whole day without having to login again.

Now there are two of us who are touching the code and as far as i'm concerned I haven't put any code that clears the `Asyncstorage`. The other one said he doesn't know either so i've been scanning the code where it removes data from `Asyncstorage` but there are none.

So my question would be, what are other possible reasons that might clear `Asyncstorage` every time the app refreshes in Expo, either when I edit something (which it automatically refresh) or when I manually refresh it from the emulator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's strange, usually `AsyncStorage` needs to be manually cleared even after a refresh. Maybe you're not properly setting values into `AsyncStorage`?

Comment: The async storage gets cleared when you clear the app data & when the phone does not have minimum required storage space.

Comment: @Jed do you get the solution? I am also having same problem

Comment: If you never clear it, you might set the token value as ```undefined``` by mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can check through VS Code's search whether you are using the `removeItem()` of Async Storage, so you don't have to manually scan each file.

[image]

If you're not using `removeItem()` in your code then you can also check the method where you are using the `setItem()` to store your token, as it may be a possibility of passing `undefined` or `null` value in it.